# Check network connection connected/disconnected

Tags: java, javascript

I am developing a web application using `java/servlet` and front end `JSP`.

My page display some information for user.

Is there any appropriate way to check if the network connection is active or not (on/off) and which supports all the browsers and devices?

If network goes down I want to redirect to some other page with appropriate message.

I read about using the `navigator.onLine` but it is not supported in all the browsers and sometimes it gives wrong results too.

Comment: You should mark an answer as correct using the ticks beside each answer or leave a comment if you're still having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native property in most browsers for this: `navigator.onLine`, however implementation of this currently varies *wildly* from browser to browser, making it very difficult to use in any real world situation.

With this in mind, I use the following javascript function to check if my pages are web connected. It is extremely simple and should work cross-browser. It works by attempting to load an image from a server and catching any errors which occur:

```
var isOnline = true;

function onlineCheck(){
    var testImg = new Image(); 
    testImg.onerror = function(){
        isOnline = false
        alert("Web access is unavailable. Please check that you are connected to the internet.")
    }
    testImg.onload = function(){ isOnline = true; }
    testImg.src = "https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo4w.png"; //replace this with an image on your site
}
```

It's a good idea to change the `testImg.src` to a 1x1pixel image on your site. This will be quicker to load, since the connection to your domain will likely already be open. I usually use a dynamicly generated image for this purpose as I find it easier to implement a few lines of code rather than creating and uploading a real image. Just in case you'd like to try this, I've included the PHP code I use to make a 1x1pixel image. You could easily adapt this to JSP:

```
        header(  "Content-type:  image/gif"); 
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate"); 
        printf ("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",71,73,70,56,57,97,1,0,1,0,128,255,0,192,192,192,0,0,0,33,249,4,1,0,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,68,1,0,59);
        exit();
```

Comment: It looks right approach to handle the network connection. do you think that, it requires to append some unique value in image src url? e.g. http://<host>/image/srpr/logo4w.ping?new Date() 
to make sure we are not always referring to cached image.
And also, do you know how the phoneGap validate the network connection?

Comment: If you're using a dynamic image, you can specify that is should not be cached as illustrated above, otherwise, yes I think appending a timestamp `new Date().getTime()` to the image src should do the same job. I believe PhoneGap connect to the device OS to check online status, rather than doing it through a browser or javascript.

Comment: Thanks, It really helps. Do you have any sample of PhoneGap which uses the device OS to check the online status?

Comment: I haven't used Phonegap much but this seems to be what you're looking for: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.6/phonegap_network_network.md.html#network.isReachable

Answer (score 1):

The only TRUE way to tell if the web app has a working connection is by calling a remote service and waiting for a response. If the request fails or times out, then you can assume there is no connection.

The trouble with the the navigator API is it'll only tell you if the device is connected to the first level, be it a router or LAN etc and not that is truly connected to the internet.

Very simply, something along the lines of the following would do the trick...

```
var appConnected = false;

function checkConnection() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.timeout = 1000 //Miliseconds - Set this to whatever you feel appropriate for your app
    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'http://yourdomain.com/1x1.gif', true);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        switch (xmlHttp.readyState) {
            case 4:
                var r = xmlHttp.responseText;

                if ( xmlHttp.status === 200 )  {
                    appConnected = true;
                } else {
                    appConnected = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                appConnected = false;
        }
    };
}

var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkConnection, 5000);
```

This would be running every 5 seconds - which depending on your particular use case might not be all that efficient. Remember to consider your users data and bandwidth.

Once you're done with polling the connection status, clear the interval with...

```
clearInterval(nIntervId);
```

Your other option would be to possibly use the fallback option in the HTML5 app cache - although if you're targeting older devices, this might not be possible.